# Theme goes away when I write .htaccess file

Tags: 7, theming, .htaccess

I had got a .htaccess file from: https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess and copied it to /var/www/drupal/.htaccess. I got to my web browser and my default theme has disappeared. I copied it to test, and my theme was back. How can I keep my theme and have .htaccess (I need it for clean URLs)?

Comment: You should have always had a .htaccess. It comes with drupal core by default. - What do yoou mean by "I copied it to test, and my theme was back"?

Comment: Also, I recommend taking drupal core from the stable release downloads at  https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal instead of from github.

Comment: I renamed the file to test and my theme came back. If so, where is .htaccess

Comment: If you download Drupal 7.31 from the page I linked, .htaccess is in there at the root/top level of drupal.

Comment: As @rooby stated, use the default download from drupal.org, the `.htaccess` file is included. Please note, that you may have to alter it slightly to get it work, e.g. from your provided information it looks like Drupal is running from a sub directory. In that case, you would need to set the `RewriteBase` in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Also, can you give more details about your default theme? Is it a drupal core theme, a custom theme or one from drupal.org or some other third party theme source? Is the theme in sites/all/themes or somewhere else?

Comment: And can you clarify "my default theme has disappeared"? Is the layout broken/images missing/styling gone/all of the above? The more info you can provide the better.